# Error while writing an Equation in LaTeX!

Tags: equations

i just started off with LaTeX. And so, getting stuck for petty issues.
Would be cool to get some help.
Here's the error i got.

> ```
> Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode.
> \add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 
>                                                   #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...
> l.39 \end{split}
> ```

and here is my code

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
E_(w) &= \frac{1}{*2}*\sum\limits_{i=1}\^ N t_i (phi{x_i}-y_i)^2 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated whether any of the answers posted so far have managed to come close to what you're hoping to achieve, typographically speaking.

Answer (score 5):

you have more issues in your equation

- instead of `\^N` you should write `\hat{N}`
- why you use `split` environment if you have on line equation?
- don't `*` use as multiplication operator
- meaning of `\frac{1}{*2}` is unclear
- instead of `phi{x_i}` i suspect that you probably like to write `\phi_{x_i}`
- ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}  
\[
E(w) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1} \hat{N} t_i (\phi_{x_i}-y_i)^2
\]
\end{document}
```

it also seems that you maybe try to write:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
E(w) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} t_i (\phi_{x_i}-y_i)^2
\]
\end{document}
```

writing of equation is demanding task ...

**edit:** considering valuable comments of [Au101](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16968/au101) and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) i make number of edits by which i try to improve my answer.

Comment: This is a good answer so far, but I think `phi{x_i}` really needs addressing

Comment: @Au101, thanks for pointing on this error. i consider this in edit of  my  answer.

Comment: You may also want to mention the possibility that `\^N`has a spurious backslash, so that it should really be `^N` (and represent the upper limit of the summation inde) and not `\hat{N}`.

Comment: @Mico, yes, this can be interpret also on this way. i will add this to answer.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks =) Great answer! I've already +1'ed, but the edits have really made the answer even better =)

Answer (score 4):

The error mainly comes from `\^` that you have written. You also need `\phi()` and no need for `split` in a one-line formula. Some terms are unclear, if you're unsure about how to typset some terms, you can post an image of the desired output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  E(w) = \frac{1}{2}*\sum\limits_{i=1}^N t_i (\phi(x_i)-y_i)^2 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Also, note that `\limits` is the default for a sum in a display, unless it's in a fraction or array as pointed out by @barbarabeeton in a comment. So, just `\sum_{i=1}^N` is sufficient in your case. And the multiplication `*` can also be removed but we are not sure about what guidelines you follow or what the desired output should be.

Comment: it might be worth mentioning that "limits" is the default for a sum in a display, unless it's in a fraction or array.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Yes, sure, I added that to the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

@Zarko and @AboAmmar have already provided valiant efforts at guessing what the equation should really look like. Here's a third guess. Note the use of the upright ("Roman") letter `E` to denote the mathematical expectation. (In math typography, italic letters are generally used for variables, whereas "operators" are generally displayed using non-italic or "Roman" letters.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\DeclareMathOperator" macro and "equation*" env.
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectations operator

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\E_w = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N t_i (\phi x_i-y_i)^2 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```